# How to create a hyperlink with large data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can smb help me with this? I have an excel file which have all sales of 1 year. In the first sheet I have Date, Sale order N, sum amount of sale etc for the whole year. In the other Sheets I have item list for each sale, date, sale order N, sum amount of the sales for each month.
I need to create a hyperlink between sale order N of Sheet 1 to the rest of the Sheets' order N, so I can click to the order N and jump to the certain order to see what items it has.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need a hyperlink, please check out this resources that will give you options on how to do different kinds of hyperlinks to other sheets/specific cells.
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-insert-hyperlink/

However, based on what you described, a suggestion may be to use a pivot table instead. You can use the data from the sheet with the details of each order and put the pivot table on the sheet that has the overall summary.

First pic is a chart with dates, sale orders, cost per item, and items included. This would be your data source table.

[image]

Second pic is the summary sheet where I've inserted the pivot table and you get the at a glance view from your summary sheet and then can filter to a specific order number to see the details of it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks much! It helped me a lot! Another issue I have with this.. I couldn't apply a hyperlink formula from vertical data to the horizontal "link location"?